# Oracle Update based on join of 2 other tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am in need of updating a huge table, >1 billion records (POS Data) with a key from a table based on a join with a third table. I can break the updates down based on dates since this goes back several years.
I basically need to replace the f.retail_sku_key in the table edw.f_pos_daily with the dedup.retail_sku_key when they are not the same.
Thanks!

```
select  F.POS_KEY, f.retail_sku_key , dedup.retail_sku_key dedup_key 
from edw.f_pos_daily f,edw.d_retail_sku sku, edw.d_retail_sku_new dedup
where f.retail_sku_key = sku.retail_sku_key
and sku.retail_sku = dedup.retail_sku
and sku.mtd_item_number = dedup.mtd_item_number
and sku.retailer = dedup.retailer
and f.retail_sku_key <> dedup.retail_sku_key
```

Comment: You can try to use BULK COLLECT FORALL update as dates specied. Best to update huge data

Comment: What is your question - how to do a correlated update? Whether to do the update in one hit or in stages based on date ranges? Something else? A single update would be most efficient, if you have enough undo space.

Comment: Alex, I would like to do a corelated update in one hit if possible. I am running on Exadata and space is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

While there's probably an UPDATE equivalent, I prefer using MERGE when a SQL statement is driving what rows need to be updated *and* generating the values to update with at the same time.

So, something like this? (I'm assuming that f.pos_key is a unique identifier on that f_pos_daily table. If that's not the case and the query returns more than one row for the same f_pos_key value, this will fail.)

```
MERGE INTO edw.f_pos_daily f_main
USING (
select f.pos_key -- this is for joining back to the rows that need to be updated...
     , dedup.retail_sku_key dedup_key -- ...and this is the value to update them with
  from edw.f_pos_daily f
     , edw.d_retail_sku sku
     , edw.d_retail_sku_new dedup
 where f.retail_sku_key = sku.retail_sku_key
   and sku.retail_sku = dedup.retail_sku
   and sku.mtd_item_number = dedup.mtd_item_number
   and sku.retailer = dedup.retailer
   and f.retail_sku_key <> dedup.retail_sku_key 
    ) qry
ON (f_main.pos_key = qry.pos_key)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET f_main.retail_sku_key = qry.dedup_key
;
```

If you did need to break this up into separate updates, you can divide in conquer in two ways:

1) Isolate partitions in f_pos_daily in the internal query (assuming the table is partitioned by something other than retail_sku_key) e.g. `FROM edw.f_pos_daily PARTITION (p_some_partition_name)` and run the above statement once for every partition

2) Generate ranges of rows to update (again, using the f_pos_key=unique assumption) that will update, say, 10% of the rows each:

```
SELECT MIN(f_pos_key) c0,
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.1) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f_pos_key) p1,
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.2) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f_pos_key) p2,
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.3) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f_pos_key) p3,
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.4) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f_pos_key) p4,
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f_pos_key) p5,
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.6) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f_pos_key) p6,
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.7) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f_pos_key) p7,
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.8) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f_pos_key) p8,
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f_pos_key) p9,
MAX(f_pos_key) c4
FROM edw.f_pos_daily;
```

If the values ranged between 0 and 1000 (and some unknown number of rows), this will give you output like:

```
P0  P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6  P7  P8  P9  P10
0   104 183 319 402 512 607 723 810 914 1000
```

From here you just need to include another condition in the subquery to have

```
AND f.pos_key BETWEEN 0 AND 104
```

on the first run then

```
AND f.pos_key BETWEEN 105 AND 183
```

on the second run, and so on.